# Error while running Vagrant up

Tags: mac-osx, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to set up Kubernetes cluster with kubeadm. As a pre-requisite I have installed VirtualBox for MacOs silicon M2 chip. Post installing, I am trying to run command "Vagrant up" and getting below error

```
    vagrant up      
Bringing machine 'kubemaster' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'kubenode01' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'kubenode02' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> kubemaster: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> kubemaster: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> kubemaster: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    kubemaster: Adapter 1: nat
    kubemaster: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> kubemaster: Forwarding ports...
    kubemaster: 22 (guest) => 2710 (host) (adapter 1)
    kubemaster: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> kubemaster: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> kubemaster: Booting VM...
==> kubemaster: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    kubemaster: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    kubemaster: SSH username: vagrant
    kubemaster: SSH auth method: private key
    kubemaster: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
```

I tried to increase the `config.vm.boot_timeout=1500` but still it didn't help.

below are my VagrantFile details

```
      # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Provision Master Nodes
  config.vm.define "kubemaster" do |node|
    # Name shown in the GUI
    node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "kubemaster"
      vb.memory = 2048
      vb.cpus = 2
    end
    node.vm.hostname = "kubemaster"
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: IP_NW + "#{MASTER_IP_START}"
    node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: "#{2710}"
    provision_kubernetes_node node
    # Install (opinionated) configs for vim and tmux on master-1. These used by the author for CKA exam.
    node.vm.provision "file", source: "./ubuntu/tmux.conf", destination: "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
    node.vm.provision "file", source: "./ubuntu/vimrc", destination: "$HOME/.vimrc"
  end

  # Provision Worker Nodes
  (1..NUM_WORKER_NODE).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "kubenode0#{i}" do |node|
      node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.name = "kubenode0#{i}"
        vb.memory = 1024
        vb.cpus = 1
      end
      node.vm.hostname = "kubenode0#{i}"
      node.vm.network :private_network, ip: IP_NW + "#{NODE_IP_START + i}"
      node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: "#{2720 + i}"
      provision_kubernetes_node node
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone help here to provide some insight on error. Am I missing some permission here or is there any issue with machine reboot? I am doing this installation first time with Vagrant so any kind o help to get through this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.